# How to call tap gesture with closure (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom UIView which have outlets. Now to set title and image I made a function which am calling in my view controller but when the user tap on the custom UIView I want to perform some action for this purpose am using tap gestures. So I made a closure to use tap gesture and I pass it as the last parameter in function but I don't know how to call the tap gesture with closure
AM SORRY IF THIS LOOK STUPID BUT JUST NEED A LITTLE HELP HERE

My IBOutlets

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var toggle: UISwitch!
```

My Closure and Tap Gesture

```
// Closure
 var onClickView: (() -> Void)?

// Tap gesture
 let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClickGestureRecognizerView))
    self.containerView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc func onClickGestureRecognizerView() {
    if let onClickView = onClickView {
        onClickView()
    }
}
```

And here is my function in which am passing title, image and this closure

```
func setSettingView(title: String, image: UIImage, onClickView: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    self.title.text = title
    self.imageView.image = image
}
```

I just wanna know when I call the function how do I perform tap action with this closure after assigning title and image

Am doing something like this

```
accountInformationSettingView.setSettingView(title: "Account Information", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "account")) {
        self.present(AccountInformationViewController.instantiateViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign passed closure in view's property.

```
func setSettingView(title: String, image: UIImage, onClickView: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    self.title.text = title
    self.imageView.image = image
    self.onClickView = onClickView
}
```

Now when you tap the view, this closure will be called

When calling setSettingView method call as follows

```
let accountInformationSettingView = CustomView()
// setup accountInformationSettingView
let tapClosure = {
    self.present(UIViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
accountInformationSettingView.setSettingView(title: "Account Information", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "account"), onClickView: tapClosure)
```

in `setSettingView` method, `tapClosure` will be assigned in `self.onClickView`

When you tap the containerView onClickGestureRecognizerView will be called and it checks whether self.onClickView is nil or not.

Then `tapClosure` will be called

Comment: Yup bro I just did it it's still not executing the code in the closure I set the breakpoint to check

Comment: @Abdullah onClickGestureRecognizerView method is called?

Comment: @Abdullah where do you have this line of code?  let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClickGestureRecognizerView))

Comment: This line is in the nib file class because I have made closure and tap gesture and function in nib file class so I can call it in my view controller

Comment: Do you have this line inside any method or have it as an instance property?

Comment: @Abdullah If you have this line outside all methods then move it to init method of the custom view

Comment: it's in the init method Rajesh
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupFromNib()
        
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClickGestureRecognizerView))
        self.containerView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

Comment: @Abdullah try to debug view hierarchy and check container view's frame

Comment: Did you tried to set `containerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay @RajeshKumar R was right it when you said call it in the init method but actually when we make custom UIView with nib there are 2 methods I was calling it in only one method so I call the method in both of the functions like this

```
 private func addGesture() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClickGestureRecognizerView))
    self.containerView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}



 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupFromNib()
    addGesture()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupFromNib()
    addGesture()
}
```

This solves the issue thanks a lot for all the help guys it really means a lot